# Trim value after 2 text patterns

Tags: regex

I have a string which I need to extract the "migration" value from (dynamic content).

The problem is that there are several patterns on the marked section.
Instead of defining 2 regex I would like to have it on single one.

```
(?i)Host: api-(.*?).A9net.io

(?i)Host: stt-(.*?).A9net.io
```

One pattern: `Host: api-**migration**.A9net.io`

Second pattern: `Host: stt-**migration**.A9net.io`

I need the migration value extracted

Answer (score 3):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either api or sst. Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
(?i)Host: (?:api|stt)-(.*?)\.A9net\.io
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hRMGP1/1)

The `(.*?)` matches 0+ times which would also match when migration is not there. In that case you could use `(.+?)` instead to at least match 1 char.

If the migration value can not contain a dot, you might also use a negated character class to match 1+ times not a dot `([^.]+)`

Comment: ...or `/(?i)(?<=Host: (?:api|stt)-).*?(?=\.A9net\.io)/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern: `(?i)^Host: (?:stt|api)-([^.]+).A9net.io$`

As already mentioned, alternation is key to your problem.

Additionally, it's recommended to use negated character class instead of lazy quantifier (such as `+?`) when possible. In this case it's `[^.]+` - it matches one or more characters other than dot, so it will match untill first occurence of a dot, which is what you want when using lazu quantifier followed by dot.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gybWb7/1)